# custom route not fails for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I create a simple MVC3 application and then I add in the following route to see if such a custom route works.

```
routes.MapRoute("self",
                "route/{message}",
                new { controller = "Route", action = "Message" }
                );
```

And I use the following url
http://localhost:2554/Route/message 
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here you are expecting a `{message}` parameter in url after the `route/` which means the engine will try to seek a default action `Message` with a parameter accepting `message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `Message` action look like?  Does it take any parameters? What type are they?

I suspect that you really want something that looks like:

```
 routes.MapRoute("self",
            "route/{message}",
            new { controller = "Route", action = "Message", message = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

with an action that looks like

```
  public class RouteController
  {
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult Message( int message )
       {
           ...
       }
  }
```

so that the URL looks like http://localhost:2554/route/1 (or some other id)

Note that the order in which the routes are specified is important.  This needs to come before the default route to be effective.